# How to manipulate the header manually when using fancyhdr?

Tags: header-footer

I would like to manipulate my header inside a chapter. So for example I want to add something like "Test" to the header, which should only be displayed on that single page.
I have tried to use `\rhead{}` but this does not work. Nothing changes on the page.

In the header, the fancyhdr package is used for the header - but I cannot identify the problem or get a solution.

I would be very glad if anyone could tell me how to do it.

This is the code used in the header:

```
\newcommand{\setpagestylehead}{%
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[L]{\vspace{0.5cm}}
        \fancyfoot[L]{
            \noindent{\tiny \\
                \begin{tabular*}{16cm}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l>{\raggedleft}p{8cm}}
                    {\tiny \langstand: \today} & 
                    {\tiny \langseite\ \thepage\ \langseitevon\ \pageref*{endOfRomanNumbering}\vspace{1cm}}\tabularnewline
                \end{tabular*}
            }
        }
    }
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
}    

\newcommand{\setpagestylecontent}{
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[L]{\vspace{0.5cm}}
        \fancyfoot[L]{
            \noindent{\tiny \\
                \begin{tabular*}{16cm}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l>{\raggedleft}p{8cm}}
                    {\tiny \langstand: \today} & 
                    {\tiny \langseite\ \thepage\ \langseitevon\ \pageref*{endOfArabicNumbering}\vspace{1cm}}\tabularnewline
                \end{tabular*}
            }
        }
    }
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
}

\newcommand{\setpagestylefoot}{
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[L]{\vspace{0.5cm}\small}
        \fancyfoot[L]{
            \noindent{\tiny\\
                \begin{tabular*}{16cm}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l>{\raggedleft}p{8cm}}
                    {\tiny \langstand: \today} & 
                    {\tiny \langseite\ \thepage\ \langseitevon\ \pageref*{LastPage}\vspace{1cm}}\tabularnewline
                \end{tabular*}
            }
        }
    }
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \pagenumbering{Alph}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting code fragments, it's much easier for people to help you if you turn your fagments into a compilable document that people can play with.

Comment: And I suspect your question is a duplicate of this one: [Change header only in one page](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/66769)